# Are there Frameworks for Integration Testing in Javascript? Which ones are good?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, jasmine, integration-testing

I need to write integration tests for javascript code. Before I did unit tests with Jasmine. Is it a good choice for integration tests, too? Or should I use a different framework? Are there any frameworks for this at all? If there are, can you tell me which ones are available and which ones are the best?
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/protractor

Comment: i am not using angularjs

Comment: @garrufa I like pioneerjs http://pioneerjs.com/